# how to inline two inouts using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

am using joomla 2.5 and twitter bootstrap. i created a form and i want to inline two inputs using twitter Bootstrap and of course preserve the responsie layout. here is my code :

```
<form name="mycontact" id="mycontact" method="post" action="">
<?php if (!empty($messages)) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <?php echo $messages; ?>
    </div><?php
}
if (!empty($succes)) {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <?php echo $succes; ?>
    </div><?php
}
?>

<p>
    <label for="nom"><strong>Nom</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom"/>


</p>
<p>
    <label for="prenom"><strong>Pr&eacute;nom</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="date"><strong>Date de naissance</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="commune"><strong>Commune</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="commune" id="commune" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="gsm"><strong>GSM</strong></label>
    <input type="tel" name="gsm" id="gsm" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="email"><strong>Email</strong></label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
</p>

<h3>Quel est votre statut actuellement</h3>
<p><label for="salarier"><input type="radio" name="statut" value="SalariÃ© plein-temps" id="salarier"/> SalariÃ© plein-temps</label></p>
<p><label for="salarier_m"><input type="radio" name="statut" value="SalariÃ© mi-temps" id="salarier_m"/> SalariÃ© mi-temps</label></p>
<p><label for="independant"><input type="radio" name="statut" value="independant" id="independant"/> IndÃ©pendant</label></p>
<p><label for="etudiant"><input type="radio" name="statut" value="Etudiant" id="etudiant"/> Etudiant</label></p>
<p><label for="passionne"><input type="radio" name="statut" value="PassionnÃ©" id="passionne"/> PensionnÃ©</label></p>
<p><label for="d_emploie"><input type="radio" name="statut" value="Demandeur d'emploi" id="d_emploie"/> Demandeur d'emploi</label></p>
<p><label for="sans_status"><input type="radio" name="statut" value="Sans statut" id="sans_status"/> Sans statut</label></p>

<div class="secteur">
    <h3>Dans quel secteur d'activitÃ© Ãªtes-vous ?</h3>
    <p><input type="text" name="secteur" id="secteur"/></p>
</div>

<div class="heure">
    <h3>Combien d'heure par semaine allez-vous consacrer Ã  une activitÃ© complÃ©mentaire</h3>
    <p><label for="heure1"><input type="radio" name="heure" value="Mois de 5 heures" id="heure1" /> Mois de 5 heures</label></p>
    <p><label for="heure2"><input type="radio" name="heure" value="De 5 Ã  8 heures" id="heure2" /> De 5 Ã  8 heures</label></p>
    <p><label for="heure3"><input type="radio" name="heure" value="Plus de 8 heures" id="heure3" /> Plus de 8 heures</label></p>
</div>

<div class="revenu">
    <h3>Quel revenu mensuel supplÃ©mentaires attendez-vous ?</h3>
    <p><label for="revenu1"><input type="radio" name="revenu" value="de 200 Ã  500 &euro;" id="revenu1" /> De 200 Ã  500 &euro;</label></p>
    <p><label for="revenu2"><input type="radio" name="revenu" value="de 500 Ã  1000 &euro;" id="revenu2" /> De 500 Ã  1000 &euro;</label></p>
    <p><label for="revenu3"><input type="radio" name="revenu" value="de 1000 Ã  2500 &euro;" id="revenu3" /> De 1000 Ã  2500 &euro;</label></p>
    <p><label for="revenu4"><input type="radio" name="revenu" value="plus de 2500 &euro;" id="revenu4" /> Plus de 2500 &euro;</label></p>
</div>

<div class="vehicule">
    <h3>Disposez-vous d'un vÃ©hicule ?</h3>
    <p><label for="vehicule1"><input type="radio" name="vehicule" value="oui" id="vehicule1" /> Oui</label></p>
    <p><label for="vehicule2"><input type="radio" name="vehicule" value="non" id="vehicule2" /> Non</label></p>
</div>

<div class="affinite">
    <h3>Avez-vous des affinitÃ©s avec le secteur des tÃ©lÃ©coms ou de l'Ã©nergie ?</h3>
    <p><label for="affinite1"><input type="radio" name="affinite" value="oui" id="affinite1" /> Oui</label></p>
    <p><label for="affinite2"><input type="radio" name="affinite" value="non" id="affinite2" /> Non</label></p>
</div>

<div class="rencontre">
    <h3>Aimez-vous recontrer des gens</h3>
    <p><label for="rencontre1"><input type="radio" name="rencontre" value="oui" id="rencontre1" /> Oui</label></p>
    <p><label for="rencontre2"><input type="radio" name="rencontre" value="non" id="rencontre2" /> Non</label></p>
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="mycontact_btn" id="my_contact_btn" value="Submit" class="btn" />
</p>
```

and here is form online : [form](http://doublerevenu.on-web.fr/)
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inline only some of your form elements, just use the [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).

```
 <div class="row">           
     <p class="span6">
         <label for="nom"><strong>Nom</strong></label>
         <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom"/>
     </p>            
     <p  class="span6">
           <label for="prenom"><strong>Pr&eacute;nom</strong></label>
           <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom"/>
      </p>
 </div>
```

Exemple on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7526/